# This program is seemingly reading a text file wrong, way too many times

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I have a program which is supposed to be reading a set of lines from a text file about train and railsystems. These include:
A line of which the current train-track is written
Subsequent lines of where all the stations on the beforementioned line are written.

The program must read these, put into separate hashmaps, and then do some other stuff as well. I am going to need every line-object to have a hasmap of all the station-object its has on its line, and every station-object to have a hashmap of all the line-objects (with hashmap of station-objects) it belongs to. However, when I run a test of the program with a print-line in the part where it should read the stations and not the line, it seemingly doesnt. It repeats the same testline so many times that my terminal cannot scroll up to the point where there are no more of them.

Please help!

The code:

```
class Oblig5{

    public static void main(String[] args){

    Planlegger starten=new Planlegger();
    starten.lesFil();

    }
}

class Planlegger{

    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

    void lesFil(){

        Linje linjer;
        Stasjon stasjoner;
        String linjeLest="";
        HashMap<String, Linje> linjerMap=new HashMap<String, Linje>();
        HashMap<String, Stasjon> stasjonerMap=new HashMap<String, Stasjon>();
        String aktuellLinje="";
        String linjeNummer="";
        char[] linjeNummerA;
        int linjeNummerInt=0;

        try{
            Scanner innFil=new Scanner(new File("Rutetabell.txt"));

            while(innFil.hasNext()){

                linjeLest=innFil.nextLine().toLowerCase();

                if(linjeLest.contains("linje")){
                    System.out.println("TESTISTASJON");
                    //Bruker en string for linjenummeret her for å lette bruken av nummeret som key i HashMapen. 

                    linjeNummerInt=Integer.parseInt(linjeLest.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
                    // linjeNummerA[0]=linjeLest.split("*linje* ").charAt(0);
                    // linjeNummer=linjeNummer[0];
                    linjer=new Linje(linjeNummer);
                    aktuellLinje=linjeNummer;
                    linjerMap.put(linjeNummer, linjer); 

                }else{
                    System.out.println("TESTISTASJON");
                    //Dersom ikke objektet finnes i hashmapen for stasjoner allerede, så lages objektet og lagres i HashMapen. 
                    if(!stasjonerMap.containsKey(linjeLest)){
                        stasjonerMap.put(linjeLest, new Stasjon(linjeLest));
                    }
                    //Her henter jeg ut objektet vi lager over, og om det ikke lages fordi det allerede eksisterer så hentes det ut uansett.
                    stasjoner=stasjonerMap.get(linjeLest);
                    //Her brukes objektinformasjonen over til å registrere stasjonen i objektet
                    linjer=linjerMap.get(aktuellLinje);
                    linjer.registrerStasjoner(linjeLest, stasjoner);
                    stasjoner.registrerNyLinje(aktuellLinje, linjer);
                }       
            }
            innFil.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Test");
        String sjekkHashmap=input.nextLine();
        if(stasjonerMap.containsKey(sjekkHashmap)){
            System.out.println("Det funker!");
        }
    }

    void beregnRuter(Stasjon fraSt, Stasjon tilSt){


    }

    void lesFraTil(){
    menySystem();
    }

    void menySystem(){
    System.out.println("Vennligst tast inn fra-stasjonen: ");
    String startStasjon=input.next().toLowerCase();
    // if(){
    // }

    }
}

class Linje{
    String linjeNummer="";
    HashMap<String, Stasjon> linjeStasjoner=new HashMap<String, Stasjon>();
    int antallStasjoner=0;    
    ArrayList<Stasjon> stasjonsList=new ArrayList<Stasjon>();

    Linje(String injeNummer){
    this.linjeNummer=linjeNummer;   
    }



    void registrerStasjoner(String linjeLest, Stasjon stasjon){
    linjeStasjoner.put(linjeLest, stasjon);
    stasjonsList.add(stasjon);
    antallStasjoner++;
    }

    boolean inneholder(Stasjon stasjon){
    boolean sannhetsSjekk=true;
    if(stasjonsList.contains(stasjon)){
        sannhetsSjekk=true;
        }else{
        sannhetsSjekk=false;
        }
    return sannhetsSjekk;
    }
}

class Stasjon{
    String stasjonNavn;
    Linje linje;
    HashMap <String, Linje> stasjonsLinjer=new HashMap<String, Linje>();
    ArrayList<Linje> linjeList=new ArrayList<Linje>();
    int teller=0;

    Stasjon(String linjeLest){
    stasjonNavn=linjeLest;
    }

    void registrerNyLinje(String aktuellLinje, Linje linje){
    stasjonsLinjer.put(aktuellLinje, linje);
    linjeList.add(linje);
    teller++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not one to question, but it appears your English-writing abilities are fine. Why do you write code in German? (I'm assuming it is German, I'm probably wrong)

Comment: It's Norweigan, not German if I'm not mistaken :)

Comment: Ah, totally my second guess xD. Anyway, this is kind of difficult to read and Google Translator isn't offering to translate it. :(

Comment: Norwegian ;) It's for a task, and they want norwegian :/

Comment: Please refrain from using phrases such as: "Please help!"

Answer (score 0):

I saw it. I made a stupid mistake of writing the same printline to both of the possibilities in the if-else loop. It seemed to work, but no idea if everything else works tho. I hope so. Please do contribute if you see any errors.